# How to access an iPhone app's media files?

Tags: ios, iphone, reverse-engineering

I've purchased a foreign language vocabulary drilling app from the Apple store. It is a simple flashcards application. Every card contains the following pieces of information:
1. a word in the source language,
2. a word in the target language,
3. an image,
4. an audio of the pronunciation of the word in the target language.

Unfortunately, the app does not have a spaced repetition engine built-in, which makes it ill suitable for memorizing the vocabulary, which consists of thousands of words. I searched for alternatives, both commercial and non-commercial, but there is nothing that comes close in terms of the selection of words and availability of audio files. I would therefore like to convert this app into an [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) deck for my own personal use.

The app's data don't show on iTunes' File Sharing, so I used [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) to create a backup of my iPhone and access this backup. One of the folders listed in the backup folder was named 'App - X', where X is the name of the app I am interested in. This folder has the following structure:
1. Library [folder]
1.1 Preferences [folder]
1.1.1  X.plist [a plain-text properties list]
2. Documents [folder]
2.1 X.sqlite [an SQLite database]

I have used [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt) to open the database and explore it. It contains a single table with a simple, obvious structure, just what one might expect. The columns for the image and audio files don't store the raw media data, but rather file names (just names, no paths), where the media are stored.

I copied the entire iPhone backup folder to my iMac's hard drive and searched for some of the file names that were listed in the media columns, but no results came up.

1. Where might I be able to find the media files?
2. This app is also available on Android. Would it be easier to obtain the media files on Android? I'd rather avoid this option, because (a) I don't have an Android, and (b) I don't want to pay twice for this app. However, if it's significantly easier to get to the media files on Android, I'll do it.

---

iOS Version 10.3.1 (14E304)

Comment: Do you have the .ipa itself? If you change the extension to zip it's a regular archive, only the executable binary is encrypted.

Comment: @Kamil.S: I don't know. How can I find out whether I have the `.ipa`?

Comment: If you fetch the app using iTunes on mac the ipas will be located here:
`~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications/`

Comment: @Kamil.S: You're officially my hero.